# Reduction of the general Lauricella hypergeometric function $F_B$ for identical parameters and variables

Tags: reference-request, sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-functions, closed-form-expressions

The Lauricella function $F_B^{n}$ of $n$ variables is defined as $$F_B^{(n)}(a_1, \ldots, a_n, b_1, \ldots, b_n, c; x_1, \ldots x_n) = \sum_{k_1, \ldots, k_n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(c)_{k_1 + \ldots + k_n}}\prod_{j=1}^n \left[\frac{(a_j)_{k_j} (b_j)_{k_j}}{k_j!} x_j^{k_j} \right],$$ where $(m)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

Is there a simple result for the reduced form of this function when all parameters and variables take on the same value, i.e., $F_B^{(n)}(a, \ldots, a, b, \ldots, b, c; x, \ldots x)$? Any reference is appreciated.